# Method each not working for getting related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each, model-associations

I write:

```
<%= Chat.find_by(id: 6).chatusers.each { |chat_user| chat_user.user.inspect } %>
```

(There are three models: Chat, Chatuser, User)

Chat.find_by(id: 6).chatusers returns collection of table "chats_users" and this is fine working.
But i can not get model user by each element of collection in method "each".
So, question is why each not working to get relative model "user" or how to resolve my task by each or another way.

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chatusers
  has_many :users, through: :chatusers

class Chatuser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "chats_users"
  belongs_to :chat
  belongs_to :user

  validates :chat_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chats, class_name: "Chatuser"
```

Thanks.

**Resolving**

Solution is using another style of ruby-html writing:

```
<% Chat.find_by(id: 6).chatusers.each do |chat_user| %> 
<%= chat_user.user.inspect %> 
<% end %>
```

Thanks for [Ruby on Rails Talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/YfdsKl9RyKE)

Comment: Can you post your `models` with `associations` in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolving**

Solution is using another style of ruby-html writing:

```
<% Chat.find_by(id: 6).chatusers.each do |chat_user| %> 
<%= chat_user.user.inspect %> 
<% end %>
```

Thanks for [Ruby on Rails Talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/YfdsKl9RyKE)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you question right, and you want to get all users for a chat, then this would do it:

```
Chat.find(6).users
```

Comment: not really, i need to get each user throw the table chats_users which getting from model Chat. Chat.find(6).chatusers.each { |chat_user| chat_user.user } ie chat_user is only object from table chats_users which correspond to the table user.